# How to force JAR dependency order after a maven dependency

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dependencies, repository

I have the following dependencies (among others):

```
    dependencies {
        compileOnly("com.destroystokyo.paper:paper-api:$paperApiVersion")
        compileOnly(files("libs/craftbukkit-1.12.2.jar"))
    }
```

I want to use all classes from the 2nd dependency under "org.bukkit.craftbukkit" group and nothing else, beacause the rest is collidating with paper-api classes (the 1st dependency). When I try to build a jar using `./gradlew shadowJar`, I'm getting errors indicating some methods inside paper-api library were not found:

```
e: /plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/hakim/common/bukkit/command/RegisterCommandRuntime.kt: (12, 49): Unresolved reference: getCommandMap
e: /plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/hakim/infrastructure/request/model/CommandHandlerRequest.kt: (22, 18): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public abstract fun sendMessage(p0: Array<(out) String!>!): Unit defined in org.bukkit.entity.Player
public abstract fun sendMessage(p0: String!): Unit defined in org.bukkit.entity.Player
e: /plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/hakim/network/ui/command/HubCmd.kt: (19, 64): Unresolved reference: toCenterLocation
e: /plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/hakim/statefulblocks/domain/StatefulBlock.kt: (23, 35): Unresolved reference: toBlockLocation
```

*paths were modified*

I know for a fact the methods exist in Bukkit class inside the paper-api library, but do not exist in the craftbukkit library.

[image: Dependencies order I get from build.gradle.kts]

I attach the screenshot to present what dependencies order I'm getting from build.gradle.kts. Pay attention where the `craftbukkit-1.12.2.jar` dependency is placed.

[image: Dependencies order I want to get from build.gradle.kts]

I attach the screenshot to present what dependencies order I want to get from build.gradle.kts. Pay attention where the `craftbukkit-1.12.2.jar` dependency is placed.

How can I achieve it?

Gradle version:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.16 (Ubuntu 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-48-generic amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue with the help from the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrZ9IJoDfkk. Instead of adding craftbukkit as a separate dependency, I'm using one containing both paper-api and craftbukkits components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).